# WordPress theme options vs custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-options, content

For dynamic content across a WordPress website, is it a better practice to create new post types for updating content or using theme options?

I personally find theme options a little more time consuming to code than registering a new post type in `functions.php`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the type of content.

Is the content dynamic, likely to change, likely to have repetitions of the same types of information, time dependent? I'll probably use a custom post type.

Is the content unlikely to change, or only needs one instance of the information set (like a logo, Google analytics code, social media usernames, etc)? Theme options.

There is another option that's sometimes viable: custom post meta-data. I'm working on a site right now where one of the pages has a list of FAQs set up in an accordion-style interface. My plan is to set up a custom meta-box specifically attached to just that page to hold the key-value pairs for the FAQs. This could be set up as a custom post type, but I'm setting it as custom post metadata. I figure this will be easier for my client, rather than having to learn, remember, and find yet another UI element.

Comment: And even in your third example, it's not questionable. You're talking about *custom post meta data*, which is something entirely different from both Theme options and Custom Post Types.

Comment: Thanks guiniveretoo! Just what I was looking for (I needed dynamics for the minor things like social media, footer/copyright, etc)